# Override application.conf variable for testing

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, scalatest

I have a Scala/Play application using settings specific to the environment. This is a part of application.conf

```
foo {
  bar {
    enabled = false
    enabled = ${?ENABLE}
  }
}
```

This will be set to true only on production environment. To test however I need to simulate production environment without editing this configuration. How can I override this variable to true using ScalaTest+Play?

Comment: Add an `application.conf` in your `test/resources` directory with desired config.

Answer (score 3):

Use `javaOptions in Test += "-Dconfig.file=conf/application.test.conf"`.

Comment: I love this tipp! Let's you nicely overwrite the defaults defined in `application.conf` by just adding `include "application.conf"` at the start of the `conf/application.test.conf` file!